# Fixing rbenv: version `ruby-2.0.0' is not installed

Tags: ruby, git, rbenv

I get the error:

```
         rbenv: version `ruby-2.0.0' is not installed
```

After I ran the following commands:

```
        git clone https://github.com/neverstopbuilding/sinatra-boilerplate.git
        cd sinatra-boilerplate
        bundle install 
        git init
        bundle exec guard
```

Even though my local and global ruby version is 2.0.0

```
Macintosh:sinatra-boilerplate jiji$ rbenv local
ruby-2.0.0
Macintosh:sinatra-boilerplate jiji$ rbenv global
2.0.0-p0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "rbenv versions" show?

Comment: @HectorCorrea it shows  system
* 2.0.0-p0 (set by /Users/.../.rbenv/version)

Comment: I don't think there is a "2.0.0" standalone, at least "rbenv versions" does not show one. This is a long shot, but try running "rbenv local 2.0.0-p0" and then re-run your commands.